# Values can't be uploaded to database

Tags: php, csv, pdo

I am trying to upload the values of the csv file to database through the fallowing code

```
    <?php
include('../connection.php');
$class = $_POST['class'];
echo "hello";

if(isset($_FILES['filename'])){
   echo "hello";
   $filename = $_FILES['filename']['name']; 
   $tmpname = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
   $filesize = $_FILES['filename']['size'];
   echo $tmpname;
   $file = fopen("$tmpname","r");

   while(!feof($file)){
     $data = fgetcsv($file);
     $q = $data[0];
     echo $q;
     $query =  $connection->prepare("INSERT into mark 
              (stuname,stuid,english,maths,science) values 
              (:stuname,:stuid,:english,:maths,:science)");
     $query->bindParam(":stuname",$q);
     $query->bindParam(":stuid",$data[1]);
     $query->bindParam(":english",$data[4]);
     $query->bindParam(":maths",$data[5]);
     $query->bindParam(":science",$data[6]);
     $query->execute();
  }
  fclose($file); 
}
?>
```

it returns me the following error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint 
violation: 1048 Column 'stuname' cannot be null in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\sprwork\admin\csv.php:25 Stack trace: #0 
C:\xampp\htdocs\sprwork\admin\csv.php(25): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} 
thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sprwork\admin\csv.php on line 25
```

but I have done `$data = fgetcsv($file)` and tried to print by storing the value in variable $q it prints but when I try to push them to my database it gives the above error

Comment: `Column 'stuname' cannot be null` is the error, update it to accept `null` values.

Comment: You try to insert null into a field that doesn't allow null as a value. Please read the error message, it makes that quite clear.

Comment: do a `var_dump($q)`. I'm pretty sure it'll happen in the last line to be null.

Comment: i din't get you I already have values in csv file, are you saying to use update statment instead of insert but does it insert to database?

Comment: @ k0pernikus  but I am not inserting null because it prints the value of $q as "qwer" according to the csv file

Comment: have a look at that comment in manual: http://php.net/manual/de/function.feof.php#67261

Comment: this is output when i did var_dump($q)  --  string(4) "qwer"

Comment: this worked fine when I just simply gave a filename and try to do it but when I did the above code it gives error and even it inserts the values of the file to database and also insert 2 empty colomns along with all the names I have written

Comment: You right I didn't realize that you have n't upload the file in your code, then i believe the problem either with the file path or the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

by the above code the values gets updated to database but it reads even null values after all the names which leads in an error I tried this and got worked

```
while(!feof($file))
        {
            $data = fgetcsv($file);
            if($class == "6" or $class == "4" or $class == "5" or $class == "7")
            {
                if($data[0] != NULL)
                {
                    $query =  $connection->prepare("INSERT into mark (stuname,stuid,english,maths,science) values (:stuname,:stuid,:english,:maths,:science)");
                    $query->bindParam(":stuname",$data[0]);
                    $query->bindParam(":stuid",$data[1]);
                    $query->bindParam(":english",$data[2]);
                    $query->bindParam(":maths",$data[3]);
                    $query->bindParam(":science",$data[4]);
                    $query->execute();
                    $count = $query->rowCount();
                }
                else
                {
                    if($count>0)
                    {
                        echo "the database is successfully updated";
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
       }
```

hence it comes out of loop after reading all colomns and for next clomn as it is null it breaks form loop and also as the last row of csv file gets updated hence thee value of $count could be 1 hence prints the value aand breaks